# The Baal Shem Tov: mitzvos as a gift

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, baal-shem-tov

I've heard in the name of the Baal Shem Tov, that G-d was wondering what to give the Jewish people in order to perfect themselves. The endresult.... mitzvos, all 613 of them.

G-d gave us the Torah and designed the mitzvos, so that we can perfect ourselves and cling to Hashem.

Is this explanation actually attributed to the Baal Shem Tov and if so, where can this idea be found? (Only Baal Shem Tov please)

Comment: I've always heard it attributed to רבי חנניא בן עקשיא.

Comment: There's also this: https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.44.1?lang=bi

Comment: @shmosel thanks for bringing that Midrash Rabbah. Still wondering what the Baal Shem Tov said :)

Comment: He says it in a few places the need to engage in Torah and Mitzvos but I havent yet seen the bit in order to cling to Hashem etc.

Comment: e.g. https://www.sefaria.org/Baal_Shem_Tov%2C_Bereshit.2.5?vhe=Sefer_Baal_Shem_Tov._Lodz,_1938&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en and https://www.sefaria.org/Baal_Shem_Tov%2C_Bereshit.52.1?vhe=Sefer_Baal_Shem_Tov._Lodz,_1938&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en